# Configuración de entorno laravel y docker me arroja error y no puedo inicializar el proyecto

Tags: php, laravel, docker

Hola comunidad tengo un problema que no estoy pudiendo resolver con la configuración de mi entorno local de laravel + docker ... ya cree las imágenes docker levanta todos los servicios tengo todos bien los puertos y subidas las bases de datos al worckbench ahora me arroja este error y ya no se que mas hacer para solucionarlo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Conexón rechazada te dice. Revisa que tengas bien configurado la conexión a BD en el archivo .env, y de limpiar la cache

Answer (score 0):

El error lo menciona claro:

> Conexión rechazada (SQL: select * from 'users' where 'email' = adanzweig@gmail.com limit 1)

No se de que tipo sea tu 'email' pero deberia estar entre comillas.

```
select * from `users` where `email` = "adanzweig@gmail.com" limit 1
```